# C# Regex replace is not working

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use RegEx to replace a string, but nothing is being replaced. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regEx = null;

regEx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("DefaultStyle.css?x=839ua9");
pageContent = regEx.Replace(htmlPageContent, "DefaultStyleSnap.css?x=742zh2");
```

**htmlPageContent** is of type string, and contains the html page content of the Render method (write before we send it to the browser). The htmlPageContent string definitely contains "DefaultStyle.css?x=839ua9". I can see it when I do Quick Watch in visual studio, and when I view Page Source.

Why is RegEx not replacing the string?

Comment: `?` is a special character.  You should not be using regex.

Comment: Use `Regex.Escape("DefaultStyle.css?x=839ua9")` if you need to pass a literal to a regex pattern.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: You're doing a direct replace. Why use Regex at all? I recommend simply using the built-in string `Replace` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `\?` and `\.` instead of `?` and `.` in your `Regex`. Please check below code.

CODE:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string htmlPageContent = "Some HTML <br> DefaultStyle.css?x=839ua9";
        string pageContent = "";

        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regEx = null;

        //regEx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("DefaultStyle.css?x=839ua9");
        regEx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"DefaultStyle\.css\?x=839ua9");
        pageContent = regEx.Replace(htmlPageContent, "DefaultStyleSnap.css?x=742zh2");

        Console.WriteLine(pageContent);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Some HTML <br> DefaultStyleSnap.css?x=742zh2
```

You can check the output in [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XLOYDa).

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your special characters using `\`.

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regEx = null;

regEx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("DefaultStyle\.css\?x=839ua9");
pageContent = regEx.Replace(htmlPageContent, "DefaultStyleSnap.css?x=742zh2");
```

You need to explicitly escape the `?` which means 0 or more of the previous character.

As for the `.` if you do not escape it, you will match any characters. It would be more precise to escape it as well to make sure you don't match something like

```
DefaultStyle-css?x=839ua9
```